# Flink SQL: How can use a Long type column to Rowtime

Tags: apache-flink

Flink1.9.1 
I read a csv file. I want to use a long type column to TUMBLE. 
I use UDF transfer Long type to Timestamp type,but is can't work
error message: Window can only be defined over a time attribute column.

I try to debug. TimeIndicatorRelDataType is not Timestamp,I don't know how to transfer and why?

```
def isTimeIndicatorType(relDataType: RelDataType): Boolean = relDataType match {
    case ti: TimeIndicatorRelDataType => true
    case _ => false
}
```

**CODE**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.setParallelism(1);

        // read csv
        URL fileUrl = HotItemsSql.class.getClassLoader().getResource("UserBehavior-less.csv");
        CsvTableSource csvTableSource = CsvTableSource.builder().path(fileUrl.getPath())
                .field("userId", BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO)
                .field("itemId", BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO)
                .field("categoryId", BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO)
                .field("behavior", BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO)
                .field("optime", BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO)
                .build();

        // trans to stream
        DataStream<Row> csvDataStream=csvTableSource.getDataStream(env).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Row>() {
            @Override
            public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Row element) {
                return Timestamp.valueOf(element.getField(5).toString()).getTime();
            }
        }).broadcast();

        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
        tableEnv.registerDataStream("T_UserBehavior",csvDataStream,"userId,itemId,categoryId,behavior,optime");
        tableEnv.registerFunction("Long2DateTime",new DateTransFunction());

        Table result = tableEnv.sqlQuery("select userId," +
                "TUMBLE_START(Long2DateTime(optime), INTERVAL '10' SECOND) as window_start," +
                "TUMBLE_END(Long2DateTime(optime), INTERVAL '10' SECOND) as window_end " +
                "from T_UserBehavior " +
                "group by TUMBLE(Long2DateTime(optime),INTERVAL '10' SECOND),userId");

        tableEnv.toRetractStream(result, Row.class).print();
```

**UDF**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
public class DateTransFunction extends ScalarFunction {
    public Timestamp eval(Long longTime) {
        try {
            Timestamp t = new Timestamp(longTime);
            return t;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**error stack**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Window can only be defined over a time attribute column.
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.rules.datastream.DataStreamLogicalWindowAggregateRule.getOperandAsTimeIndicator$1(DataStreamLogicalWindowAggregateRule.scala:85)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.rules.datastream.DataStreamLogicalWindowAggregateRule.translateWindowExpression(DataStreamLogicalWindowAggregateRule.scala:90)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.rules.common.LogicalWindowAggregateRule.onMatch(LogicalWindowAggregateRule.scala:68)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.AbstractRelOptPlanner.fireRule(AbstractRelOptPlanner.java:319)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRule(HepPlanner.java:560)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRules(HepPlanner.java:419)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.executeInstruction(HepPlanner.java:256)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepInstruction$RuleInstance.execute(HepInstruction.java:127)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.executeProgram(HepPlanner.java:215)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.findBestExp(HepPlanner.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.Optimizer.runHepPlanner(Optimizer.scala:228)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.Optimizer.runHepPlannerSequentially(Optimizer.scala:194)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.Optimizer.optimizeNormalizeLogicalPlan(Optimizer.scala:150)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.StreamOptimizer.optimize(StreamOptimizer.scala:65)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.StreamPlanner.translateToType(StreamPlanner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.StreamPlanner.org$apache$flink$table$planner$StreamPlanner$$translate(StreamPlanner.scala:182)
```

Comment: Could you try to use `.field("optime", Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP)`? That should convert the long into timestamp that you can use for windowing operations.

Comment: it can't be work.
it same as  UDF trans to Timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already managed to assign a timestamp in DataStream API, you should be able to call:

```
tableEnv.registerDataStream(
    "T_UserBehavior",
    csvDataStream,
    "userId, itemId, categoryId, behavior, rt.rowtime");
```

The `.rowtime` instructs the API to create column with the timestamp stored in every stream record coming from DataStream API.

The community is currently working on making your program easier. In Flink 1.10 you should be able to define your CSV with rowtime table directly in a SQL DDL.